# Reading time duration with dplyr or lubridate

Tags: r, time, dplyr, lubridate

In my csv file I have a character column of the format "0 days 00:00:17.740000000" that represents time durations. How can I read this in with dplyr (`read_csv`) as a time duration or transform it after reading with lubridate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an assumption that all of dates have similar structure.
Simulated data:

```
set.seed(12345)

days <- sample(0:20, 10, replace = T)
hours <- sample(0:24, 10, replace = T)
mins <- sample(0:60, 10, replace = T)
secs <- sample(0:60, 10, replace = T) + runif(10, 0, 1)

DF <- data.frame(date = sprintf('%s days %s:%s:%s', days, hours, mins, secs))
```

Then we separate days "by hand", convert types and recombine everything into a `period`:

```
library('tidyr')
library('lubridate')
library('dplyr')

DF %>%
  separate(date, c('days', 'time'), sep = ' days ') %>%
  mutate(elapsed = period(days = as.numeric(days)) + hms(time))

   days               time                   elapsed
1    15 00:27:48.782193281  15d 0H 27M 48.782193281S
2    18  03:19:0.429198820    18d 3H 19M 0.42919882S
3    15 18:58:11.927273975 15d 18H 58M 11.927273975S
4    18 00:43:41.773243225  18d 0H 43M 41.773243225S
5     9 09:39:22.259681247   9d 9H 39M 22.259681247S
6     3 11:23:22.321224673  3d 11H 23M 22.321224673S
7     6 09:42:52.060195157   6d 9H 42M 52.060195157S
8    10 10:33:55.043456454 10d 10H 33M 55.043456454S
9    15 04:13:37.055053818  15d 4H 13M 37.055053818S
10   20  23:29:8.625542797  20d 23H 29M 8.625542797S
```